# the requested resource does not support http method 'get'. Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

i am searching for a solution to my Problem quite a while. I am finding many answers to my question, but cant figured it out.
Here is my Problem:
I am trying to send a json file to another Domain (its an external firm with an Web API for cooperation firms), which should send me back some json (I am using MVC WebApps), without using the Controller...
First of all i had the Problem with Cross-Domain, which i tried to figured out with editing the Web.config (see above).

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" /> 
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" /> 
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" /> 
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This did not help. After using jsonp (see my following jc Code), this Problem was solved. But now i get the **"The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'"** - Errormsg.

```
<script>
    $("#getprice").click(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            asnc: false,
            Accept: "application/json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: 'localJsonpCallback',
            url: "otherdomain.com" + "?callback=?",
            data: {
                models: [{
                    toolID: "",
                    modelReference: "some model.xml",
                    materialID: $("#materialID").val(),
                    finishID: $("#finishID").val(),
                    quantity: $("#quantity").val(),
                    xDimMm: $("#xDimMm").val(),
                    yDimMm: $("#yDimMm").val(),
                    zDimMm: $("#zDimMm").val(),
                    volumeCm3: $("#volumeCm3").val(),
                    surfaceCm2: $("#volumeCm3").val()
                }],
                shipmentInfo: [{
                    countryCode: $("#countryCode").val(),
                    stateCode: "",
                    city: $("#city").val(),
                    zipCode: $("#zipCode").val()
                }],
                currency: $("#currency").val()
            },
               xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true
        })
    })
    function localJsonpCallback(json) {
        if (!json.error) {
            alert("läuft");
            console.log(json);
        } else {
            alert(json.Message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

While searching for a solution, i only find this [HTTPPOST] Info for your Controller. But my Problem here, i do not use the Controller as buffer. I directly send the data from my View to the Server and back.

Comment: Can you show the `Action` method you are posting to?

Comment: as i explained, i am not responding to an Action method in my Controller. Is this my Problem? i would like to send the info right back to the html form file in the "solution" text box. So in this case, my localJsonpCallback function should send the info to the html id tag

Comment: try `otherdomain.com` without `?callback=?` as your url

Comment: i tried with and without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it!
After not finding a solution the direct way, i took the Controller as my intermediate... Sending the form data to the Controller, which has a JsonResult Action method. And in this methode i communicate via HttpWebRequest to my external Web Api, and sending via Httpreponse the json data back to my view.

Oh me oh my oh gosh...